# Question not seeking debugging help closed for seeking debugging help without MCVE?

Tags: discussion

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39991033/combine-all-properties-in-two-objects-using-javascript).

It was closed by five voters for the "seeking debugging help" reason. That was obviously ridiculous, since it was not seeking debugging help to start with.

I flagged this, with the following note:

> This question is not seeking debugging help, so how can it be closed for that reason? It's a perfectly valid question. close-voters think the OP should have provided an attempt, then they should down-vote for not showing enough research effort, not close-vote. If they think it's a duplicate--and there are definitely related questions on the site--then they should find them and vote to close as a duplicate.

The moderator responded:

> declined - I'm guessing they seized on the MCVE aspect here. If you feel it should be reopened, you are free to vote for that.

I don't understand. How can it be OK for them to "seize" on the MCVE aspect when the very premise of this close reason--that it is seeking debugging help--does not apply here? People can downvote all they want, but I don't see why it's OK to close for wrong reasons. It's a manifestation of the phenomenon we have all seen where people "double downvote" by giving a made-up close reason.

Comment: The moderator isn't saying that it's OK. He's just surmising what the close voters' thought process was, and suggesting that you cast a normal reopen vote when you disagree with a close reason, instead of flagging for a moderator.

Comment: @BoltClock So maybe I'm misunderstanding flags and/or the role of the moderator. Is that idea that obviously flawed/wrong close votes are not something to flag, or for moderators to deal with? Sure I could vote to re-open, but that's pretty close to doing nothing, given the chances of four other people to come along and also vote to re-open.

Comment: Vote to reopen first, and if nothing seems to be coming out of it, flag for a moderator.

Answer (score 10):

Like we have nothing better to do with our votes ...

You're right. That question shouldn't have been closed as NO MCVE. It could have been closed as Too Broad or even as a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically), and that has answers with jQuery so it must be a good one.

Do note that not only 5 voters choose to close that question, also [3 others](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/13956274) decided to leave it closed. So already 8 users didn't think that question was worth keeping. The down votes made the question eligible for the Roomba which happened yesterday.

Now it can be confusing for OP's when their post is closed and a wrong reason is given. In this case I can see why *also* the MCVE one was applicable as for the code they showed it wasn't clear what did work and what didn't or even if it did run. In that sense pointing the OP to the MCVE close reason can be helpful, where too broad probably didn't help. And yes, down voting such lack of effort posts is a wise thing to do.

So by casting an un-delete vote and re-open vote I helped a bit so we can do The Right Thing™ which seems to be down voting, close voting and delete voting. *instead we made a train-wreck out of it :(*

Comment: Let's also hope that The Right Thing™ includes *not* deleting it.  It's hovering at 2 delete votes right now and I get this sinking feeling that someone's going to tip it over the scale *very* soon.

Comment: @Makoto Why do we need that question on the site? There are duplicates already, it shows no effort or research, and is basically someone asking us to do their work for us. If you'd like more examples of that kind of question, I'm sure anyone in the `javascript` tag can come up with more than a few for you...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan:  The whole *point* of bringing it back is to point to the duplicate.  There's no other value besides that; at a bare minimum, the OP will have a reference to go off of rather than nothing useful.  I'd rather see it closed as a duplicate which may actually have a chance of helping the OP than have it deleted or removed from the site outright.

Comment: @Makoto But the question would not make a good duplicate "signpost", because it was a code dump with barely a sentence of explanation. The OP can search the internet for themselves; searching on the title of the question returns [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/171251/215552) as the first hit, which would get them where they need to go.

Comment: Confused about why it would be called a "code dump", or a reference would be made to **the code they showed**. No code was showed, or dumped. The OP didn't know where to start, which is not an unreasonable place to be. The point is that the 5 voters **chose to close for invalid, unreasonable reasons**. You are giving too much credence to folks with itchy fingers on the closevote button. There is no abstract notion of "worth keeping". There are downvotes, which are completely up to the discretion of the voter, and then there are **valid**, **justified** close votes.

Comment: @torazaburo sure and those valid, justified close votes just happened. Let's move on.

Comment: As a quick-note, even if we forget all the close votes and (un)delete votes and downvotes there after this Meta question, that particular SO question, even closed as duplicate, would have still been roombad in [roughly 2 weeks](http://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba). And this is not saying the close reason was appropriate, it certainly wasn't, and duplicate clearly would have been better. But since we're discussing this particular question... it actually wouldn't have changed anything. To discuss the appropriateness of close votes in a general manner, it would be better to make a separate post.

Comment: And yes the question was roombad before... so after closing it as duplicate, it would have been roombad a second time, if this is even a thing...

Comment: @torazaburo: "*The point is that the 5 voters chose to close for invalid, unreasonable reasons.*" No, the point is that a question which deserved to be closed **was closed**. Was it closed with the right close reason? Probably not. But that's far less important than the fact that a question which ought to be closed has been closed.

Comment: @NicolBolas Umm, what was the right close reason?

Comment: @rene The entire point of my post, as I would have thought would have been clear, is that those close votes were **not** valid or justified, by any interpretation. Essentially, you are saying that anyone can close anything for any reason at any time in the face of any set of facts to the contrary. If that is so, let's just get rid of all the close reasons and replace them with a single one saying "I don't like this question and think it should be closed".

Comment: @torazaburo you have made that clear. Thanks.

Comment: @torazaburo Actually, what you were told was that it's not worth the effort to undelete a question, reopen it, just so that you can then close it for a different reason and re-delete it.  Nobody has told you that it's fine to close any quesiton for any reason, they've just told you that when a close-worthy question is closed for a wrong, or less applicable, reason, it's not really worth fixing, all the more so when it's deleted.

Comment: @torazaburo: "*Umm, what was the right close reason?*" Well, right now it is closed as a duplicate. So let's go with that.

Comment: @torazaburo Since I wallow in the mire of <10K, I was working off of the screenshot provided by user000001 in their answer, which shows a lot of code with little explanation. This is what I classify as a "code dump".

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan It's not a code dump. It's showing the desired input and output.

Comment: @torazaburo My mistake. It's a work request.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I hate work requests as much as the next guy, even to the extent of violating my own rule and making up random close reasons for them. (By the way, there **is** no close reason for "code this for me"--as you will see if you look closely.) However, in this case, the underlying problem seems interesting and useful, and it is easily conceivable that the OP did not know where to start. One can view it as an algorithm question. One way to answer could have been to give an approach, rather than to give code.

Comment: @torazaburo If you had spent half as much energy improving the question to a point where it wasn't such crap as you have defending your position, we wouldn't be having this discussion.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan This was never about the particular question. It was about people using random, inapplicable close reasons to close vote question they don't like. Actually, it was already answered early in the thread: vote to re-open, then possibly raise a flag if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I believe "no MCVE" is "be nice" close reason as any other action on that post would presume lack of effort on OP part.

If I assume user made honest effort to research the question (like searched for "JavaScript combine two objects" or even "JavaScript extend"), than at that point it is reasonable to expect they need help with implementation and not to explain the same thing over and over again. And here you have "no MCVE" as close reason from me.

Alternative - downvote and vote to close and claim OP did not bother to make any effort... While likely true it may not fit to ["be nice"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) policy.

Comment: You seem to think that one first decides to close on some abstract grounds, and then goes rummaging around to find a close reason that fits some criteria such as "being nice". But actually, one should close vote **if** there's a close reason that actually fits, and not close vote if there's not. In this case, to repeat myself, the "debugging" close reason does **not** fit. Instead, the OP does not know where to begin. He doesn't even know the terms "merge" or "deep merge". If that level of ignorance, or failure to do research, is worthy of downvoting, then fine, downvote away.

Answer (score -5):

Here is a screenshot of the question so it can be discussed now that it is deleted: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6WUQ.png

I agree with you that the question is on-topic, so I voted to reopen it.
Your flag got declined though because you were asking a moderator to do something that you could do by yourself: to vote to reopen. He probably thought that the flag was unneccesary.

Comment: So you want this undeleted and then re-opened which seems to be a broad question, assuming there isn't a dupe?

Comment: @rene sure, why not? Merging two objects seems a task that could be useful to wide audience.

Comment: It is utter crap but I casted an undelete vote to see how many wondeful answers that will get

Comment: It is undeleted now, reopen vote casted

Comment: And it is deleted again

Comment: @psubsee2003 It's been reopened and is waiting on more undelete vote before it will be a live, open question